# Get pending user information to a Facebook group

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been stumbling around the Facebook Graph API Reference for about a week trying to get acquainted and find what I'm looking for, but I'm feeling pretty stumped so far.

I'm trying to get a list of *pending* members to a *closed* group that I'm and admin for.

For each pending member, I'd like to get either:

- Their street address (used to be field 'location', apparently deprecated in v2.0?)
- Answer to a Group Question (what is their street address).

I've gotten as far as getting a list of current members to the group.

I'm trying to setup an Admin app specifically for my group to help speed up the validation of incoming user. The group is a housing development community group, primarily used to communicate events or issues (mostly issues...). Previous versions of the group attracted people from neighboring housing communities though, which defeats the purpose of a specific Facebook group.

Comment: I didn't realize there were ways to automate Facebook Group Admin.  I am the sole Admin of a FB Group with over 8K members,  I would love to have a way to automate some of the tasks (like membership approval).

Comment: I don't think there is a native way of automating. I'm currently trying to automate some of the roles in another website that I"m developing. Unfortunately, not all the information seems to be accessible from Graph API. But, I'm new to this API, so who knows...

Comment: Are you a member of the FB Admin Group (it is run by FB)?
https://www.facebook.com/groups/adminsfeedback/
If you want to connect on FB, I can add you.